# How do certificate authorities choose which private/public keys to use to encrypt each SSL certificate so a browser can know that they're legit?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

My understanding is that for each SSL certificate, there is a private and public key that web browsers use to confirm that it is a valid certificate signed by a trusted Certificate Authority.

How does the Certificate Authority decide which private key and public key will be used to encrypt each certificate for verification by the browser? Do they have different private/public keys for each certificate?

Comment: What do you call a *SSL certificate*?

Comment: In short: the public key is provided by the party which wants to have the certificate inside a certificate signing request (CSR). The private key is kept private by this party, i.e. not known to the CA. A certificate is basically the provided public key augmented with added meta data about the validity of the certificate (subject, expiration, ...), signed (not encrypted!!) by the CA.

Comment: I googled "ssl certificate" and the top 3 hits were sites providing info that contradicts your core understanding. Please do some research before asking questions.

Comment: Welcome to a long term ban ... Fixing grammar is not a personal critique or a slight on your character. That you took it so personally is an indication of an issue on your part, not mine. If you read more carefully, you will also see that I did not close the question, and the closing as a duplicate is not "gatekeeping" but rather pointing you to the answer you requested. The fact that your core misunderstanding of the topic is resolved so easily is your opportunity for growth, not an opportunity to lash out.